# How to save Bitmap to PNG file without causing error

Tags: vb.net, image-processing, bitmap, gdi+

I want to encode a bitmap as PNG and then save it to a file.
But my `heatmap_PictureBox_Bitmap.Save( filepathname )`
..causes the error:

> A generic error occurred in GDI+.

`heatmap_PictureBox_Bitmap` contains a color image.

This displays the picture just fine on my .NET app on Windows 10:

```
public const  MOBILE_UPLOADER_PATH = "C:\demo\DEMO4\MOBILE UPLOADER\"
public const XY_HEATMAP_PNG_FILENAME = "XY_HEATMAP.PNG"
public const  XY_HEATMAP_PNG_PATHNAME = MOBILE_UPLOADER_PATH     & XY_HEATMAP_PNG_FILENAME  

dim heatmap_PictureBox_Bitmap   as Bitmap
. . .

' Build the image bitmap:
for x = 0 to x_range
  for y = 0 to y_range
    ' red, green, blue are integers 0 to 255
    pixel_color = Color.FromArgb( red, green, blue )
    heatmap_PictureBox_Bitmap.SetPixel( x, y, pixel_color   )  
  next
next
. . .
PictureBox_heat_map.Image = heatmap_PictureBox_Bitmap  ' displays ok
```

But adding this line (below) causes the error "A generic error occurred in GDI+."

```
. . .
heatmap_PictureBox_Bitmap.Save( XY_HEATMAP_PNG_PATHNAME  ) <<<< CAUSES THE ERROR
PictureBox_heat_map.Image = heatmap_PictureBox_Bitmap
```

My assumptions:
1. `heatmap_PictureBox_Bitmap` is non-encoded/compressed image data
2. `bitmap.save( pathname )` encodes as .PNG

I also tried

```
heatmap_PictureBox_Bitmap.Save(XY_HEATMAP_PNG_PATHNAME, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
```

..same problem.

Directory in XY_HEATMAP_PNG_PATHNAME exists.

Comment: How do you load it? There are some rules you need to follow when loading images, like not disposing the stream they're made from. Also, please post some actual code, not just pseudocode. We can't see what goes wrong from an approximation of your code.

Comment: I just added code for how bitmap is created

Comment: Sorry, with the given code I don't get any errors at all. You're going to need to give more detail.

Comment: The VB editor fixes casing and spacing. This cannot be the real code. How are you creating or loading the bitmap?

Comment: I turn off casing and spacing in my VS editor.  it's the real code. I will provide more details.

Comment: Will bitmap.Save(…) work for a bitmap created with .SetPixel()?

Comment: Setting the extension to `png` has no affect on the encoder used to write the file.  Use the overload that specifies the `ImageFormat` to use to encode the saved image.  Currently valid encoders are: BMP. JPE, GIF, TIFF, and PNG.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the destination folder 
public const  MOBILE_UPLOADER_PATH = "C:\demo\DEMO4\MOBILE UPLOADER\"
..did not exist.

I had assumed that it existed.

I modified the code to create the folder if it doesn't exist.